# restore previous entry of textbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, validation

am doing validating textbox as below,suppose overwrite textbox entry with an invalid number message will pop up,after clicking "OK" I want previous valid entry which is overwritten to be displayed.

how can i do that in C#?

```
private void cor_o_gain_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int entered = int.Parse(cor_o_gain.Text);
        if (entered > 255)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Enter the number between 0 and 255");
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
      //  e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also simply call the **Undo()** method (in case you are talking about the Windows Forms TextBox)

Comment: yeah...that is ok...in case once again i enter invalid number,it displays previous number(which is invalid!),I want only the last valid entry to be displayed..

Answer (score 1):

There is no default built-in way to do that. You'll just have to save the old value yourself (in some variable) and then restore it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use DataBinding and it will do it for you and it has a method for parsing data that will allow you to perform your validation

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply store the current text when the Validated event occures, so you can use it next time?

Answer (score 1):

as said by **Codymanix**

replace `e.Cancel = true;` to  `cor_o_gain.Undo();`

Comment: yeah...that is ok...in case once again i enter invalid number,it displays previous number(which is invalid!),I want only the last valid entry to be displayed..

Comment: What values you are trying for?